# Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag error during migration from WildFly 23 to WildFly 30

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

I have a simple Spring Boot Web Application (API) that has been wonderfully deployed on WildFly 23. However, I decided to try to embed it on WildFly 30. The deployment was successful, but according to the endpoints of my application, I get a 404 Not Found error. There are many messages of the following nature in the server logs:
`[org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag in Module ... from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag ... from Service Module Loader): javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes.`
Experts, please tell me what might be the matter.
Java EE 11.

I tried changing the Java version in pom.xml in the project file, I tried to change the version of spring-boot-starter-parent, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

WildFly 30 is a Jakarta EE 10 container. You need to migrate to the Jakarta EE 10 API's. Spring Boot 3.x uses Jakarta EE 9 API's which should work on WildFly 30. A Jakarta EE 8 application will not work in a Jakarta EE 10 container.

You'd need to migrate your application from the `javax` namespace to the `jakarta` namespace as well.